# Time difference in seconds gives me wrong answers

Tags: java, parsing, date, date-format

I have two date strings and I want to know how many seconds difference there is between them.

```
2014-05-19 16:37:36:690  // formattedDate
2014-05-19 19:38:00:000  // expString
```

I use the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

d1 = sdf.parse(expString);
d2 = sdf.parse(formattedDate);


long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
long exp = diff / 1000 % 60;
```

In this particular example `exp` is `23`. What is the problem here?

Comment: `anything % 60` will always give an answer between `0` and `59`.  What were you expecting to see?

Comment: and what is the result when updated ? Because it's OBVIOUSLY the reason of your problem

Comment: What answer were you expecting? If you look at the dates you are subtracting (mod 60), you get `60 - 36.69 = 23.31` which rounds to `23` when you convert it to a long.

Comment: And if you don't mod by 60, you get `10823` seconds, which is 3 hours, 23 seconds, which is the actual difference between those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.  So `diff` has the time in milliseconds between the two dates.

```
long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
// diff = 10882310
```

You user integer division to get to seconds, which drops the extra milliseconds.

```
long temp = diff / 1000;
// temp = 10823
```

Then you modulus by 60, which gets you seconds and ignores seconds that were attributed to minutes.

```
long exp = temp % 60;
// exp = 23
```

If you want the total time in seconds between the two dates, you don't want to do that last operation.

Comment: But 3 hours is not 83 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use modulus division! Just use plain division:

```
long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
long exp = diff / 1000;
```

Better yet, use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum from the JDK:

```
long exp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) offers a [`Seconds`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html) class to just what you want.

The Joda-Time library also has classes to represent spans of time: [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), and [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). You don’t strictly need them for this specific question, but they will be handy for related work.

Below is some untested code off the top of my head.

For simplicity, convert your strings to strict ISO 8601 format. Replace the SPACE with a `T`.

```
String inputStart = "…".replace( " ", "T" );
// same for stop
```

Create date-time objects. Explicitly assign a time zone by which to parse those strings. Are that UTC?

```
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime( inputStart, DateTimeZone.UTC );
// repeat for stop

long secs = Seconds.secondsBetween( startDateTime, stopDateTime ).getSeconds();
```